# MailboxSettings always null using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Issue:

Using C# library, trying to get user's `mailboxsettings` but it is always `null` as a property of User class

I try to get the `mailboxsetting` like below:

```
return (await client.Users["userid"].Request().GetAsync()).MailboxSettings;
```

But it always returns `null`.

But when I try to use the rest API by sending request `/beta/users/{id}/mailboxSettings`, it works.

Is it that the `mailboxsettings` hasn't been exposed in User class?

Answer (score 1):

You should build your request like:

```
var result = await client.Users["userid"].Request().Select("MailboxSetting").GetAsync().Result;
var mailboxSettings = result.MailboxSettings;
```

So you will get the `MailboxSettings`.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be an issue in the Graph SDK. You should file an issue on their GitHub repository https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues.

The problem seems to be that getting mailbox settings requires another request, but the SDK treats it like a normal property on the User object.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had this problem as well. After fiddling with permissions I got the code posted by Larissa to work.

**Microsoft Graph Application Permissions**

- Read all user's full profiles
- Read and write all users mailbox settings

**Windows Azure Active Directory Delegated Permissions**

- Read all user's basic profiles